# Cant access files on ubuntu EC2 AWS instance

Tags: php, android, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, apache2

I've created apache2 ubuntu instance, added a database and a PHP file to it using FileZilla. I copied the PHP file's URL from FileZilla and I get a 404 error when trying to call it from my android application, anyone knows why I cant access files from the instance?

This is the URL I copy: `sftp://ubuntu@54.171.67.69/home/ubuntu/register.php`

This is the error I'm getting on Android studio:
`E/Volley: [173] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://ec2-54-171-67-69.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/home/ubuntu/register.php`

Update: So when I put the link I copied from the browser it takes me to and index.html file and I found that file through terminal on '/var/www/html/' but this directory is not shown on FileZilla, all I need now is to figure out how to add files to this directory and I should be sorted.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your current code, attempts and outputs are required for others to assist you. Please see [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to revise your question for better clarity. A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would also be appreciated.

Comment: Theres no point showing the code as I know the problem is not there, this is the URL I copy sftp://ubuntu@54.171.67.69/home/ubuntu/register.php from FileZilla and this is the error I'm getting on Android studio:
E/Volley: [173] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://ec2-54-171-67-69.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/home/ubuntu/register.php

Comment: Relevant pieces of code are still meant to be part of the question. The URL should, as an example, definitely be included.

You say you've uploaded it to a server via FTP. Why are you linking it via SFTP, instead of using its web URL? Where did you upload it? The output seems to go to an AWS Compute instance - do you have a /home folder in there to begin with? Notice how many questions are left opened because your question is vague?

Comment: I don't mean to be vague Im just new to all this, the SFTP link is what was copied from FileZilla where the file was uploaded into the home directory of the instance. I changed the beginning of the link to http when running it on java.

Comment: I know you're new, that's why it appeared in the review queue, and that's why I'm trying to give you some advise! :) If you log into your Amazon instance, is there a way for you to generate an actual link from there?

Comment: Yes, it gives me the same address. "ec2-54-171-67-69.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com" This address by it self works fine, its when I try to add the path to the php file that it doesn't find it.
I can shh into the instance through terminal and when I do ls I can see the file is there.

Comment: Where, relative to the document root, is the file? I would venture to guess it's not in the right directory to allow web access.

Comment: When I copy the link from FileZilla the root is '/home/ubuntu/register.php' can the directory change for web addresses?

Comment: Likely not. You're more likely going to have to move the file. Honestly, this issue does not seem to belong on SO - it is, from what I can tell, an issue with AWS or not understanding how to use it.